# Why doesn't google.com show the voice search feature in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript

In Chrome, google.com has a microphone search feature, as seen here:
[image: Google Search with microphone]

In Firefox though, it doesn't:
[image: Google Search with no microphone]

In Firefox, I tried setting the user agent to Chrome's (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36) in about:config > general.useragent.override expecting to receive the page served to Chrome, and now it weirdly flickers as shown here https://youtu.be/UpYh20YVIh4

What is causing this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the microphone icon to stay by enabling (setting to True) those two in addition to changing the User Agent:

```
media.webspeech.recognition.enable
media.webspeech.recognition.force_enable
```

However, it was still not getting the audio from my microphone, it just said waiting:
[image]

Based on online chatter, this has to do with the way the Speech-to-text service works, and cannot work on Firefox (and it also doesn't work on many Chromium based browsers, like Opera and Vivaldi.)

Comment: How does the Speech-to-text service work?

Comment: On Chrome it is using the Web Speech API see info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API (and demo https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html)

Comment: why doesn't firefox support this?

Comment: The reason is that it is not a local (computer program, which Firefox is) thing, Google uses a server-based recognition engine for this, so for Mozilla to develop that it's a whole different ball game. And it's also a whole new machine learning project to be able to recognize speech.

Comment: but why can't Firefox connect to Google's recognition engine?

Comment: At some point they tried, see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Web_Speech_API_-_Speech_Recognition, not sure why that didn't work out. It's possible that Google didn't allow them to